# How can I determine what a fund is composed of

Tags: etf

I have money in some ETFs / mutual funds, such as xme, vtiax, vyml, and vgt.  Until now I have considered them 100% stock, when balancing my portfolio.  It is occurred to me that maybe these are actually composed of stocks and bonds both (and perhaps other asset types?)  I've done some searching around, but no luck; how can I find out the percentage of stocks in each?

Comment: Looks like you can see the vanguard ones through a link at the bottom of the vanguard investor page ("portfolio holdings"), or change VTIAX to the fund you want to see in this URL: https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/overview/VTIAX/portfolio-holdings

Comment: @Kevin - thank you.  Looks like it will be hard to figure a percentage of each type, based on this info though